# No Sound in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa

My laptop has sound problem since I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and if I check my sound settings, there is no device for sound output to choose.

Here is a link to the full [ALSA INFORMATION SCRIPT](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=4f...e7d4e9094bd89e), below do follow the first lines of this script:

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Wed Oct 17 17:17:18 UTC 2018


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS" HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
Product Name:      X555LAB
Product Version:   1.0       
Firmware Version:  X555LAB.503


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    4.15.0-36-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k4.15.0-36-generic
Library version:    1.1.3
Utilities version:  1.1.3


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xb021c000 irq 49


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)


!!Advanced information - PCI Vendor/Device/Subsystem ID's
!!-------------------------------------------------------

00:03.0 0403: 8086:0a0c (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: 1043:19ad
--
00:1b.0 0403: 8086:9c20 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: 1043:19ad


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
```